# Caliburn.Micro with controller?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controller, caliburn.micro

Is it possible to use the `Caliburn.Micro` (CM) framework for a WPF app without initialising the app with a `bootstrapper`? Instead, I want to use a controller to start the app, initialise ViewModels and Services.

In short, my current MVVM-based WPF application is running with a Controller on top and now I want to integrate the CM into it without changing the controller-based architecture. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. From the CM documentation and architecture, you need to use `bootstraper`, in order to configure CM, like root view model, IoC stuff, etc. You can read more about it here: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper&referringTitle=Documentation

Why do you want to use your own controller instead? From my experience, if you do the things CM advocates, you'll gonna have a nice and smooth ride in WPF MVVM.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that using a bootstrapper is a must. and it's confirmed now. I understand that CM gives us everything necessary to make a MVVM WPF. It's just I've been developing one without CM, and having a controller on top of the application to bootstrap everything, including app configuration and services injection. CM's bootstrapper does pretty much the same thing and I just don't want to break the current architecture when I want to set up the app to use CM.